# Prefetching Cachelines on x86-64 using PREFETCHh

Tags: caching, assembly, x86-64, timing

I was trying to measure timing differences in memory access based on different cache-levels.

In order to load data to specific cache-levels I used the PREFETCHh instruction, following this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

But I the results didn't show any difference in timing and I found another source telling a totally different story: 
http://www.tptp.cc/mirrors/siyobik.info/instruction/PREFETCHh.html

EDIT: Nevermind, I interpreted "level 2 cache and higher" in the wrong direction, both sources describe the same behavior.

Which would explain my results. Can somebody tell me which source is right and if there is a way of measuring the timing differences of particular cache levels like this?

Comment: The second link is a (bad) conversion of the official pdf, which is the authoritative source.

Comment: The PREFETCHh instructions are completely asynchronous, its effects, if any, can happen any time after the instruction is executed. It's just a hint to the CPU that the memory referenced is going to be accessed soon, and to be at all useful it needs to be issued sufficiently in advance of the access to give the CPU time to load the data into the cache. It's probably not useful for what you're doing, at least not without knowing the specific cache behaviour of the CPU you're using it on.